# FUNCTION_REGION env variable in Nodejs is differenrent than GCP set automatically for logs

Tags: google-cloud-logging

I programmatically write the logs from the function using such code:

```js
import {Logging} from '@google-cloud/logging';

const logging = new Logging();
const log = logging.log('log-name');

const metadata = {
  type: 'cloud_function',
  labels: {
    function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
    project: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
    region: process.env.FUNCTION_REGION
  },
};

log.write(
  log.entry(metadata, "some message")
);
```

Later in Logs Explorer I get the log message where `labels.region` is **us1** whereas standard logs that GCP adds, e.g. "Function execution started", contains **us-central1** value.

Should not they be the same? Maybe I missed something or if it was done intentionally what is the reason behind it?

Comment: The ` process.env.FUNCTION_REGION` was available in Node 8 which was deprecated. Which runtime are you using?

Comment: I use Node 14. Thanks for pointing this out, it's not supported in this runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.env.FUNCTION_REGION` is supported only in Node 8 runtime. In newer runtimes it was deprecated. More info in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#runtime_environment_variables_set_automatically).

> If your function requires one of the environment variables from an older runtime, you can set the variable when deploying your function.